# Change color of button from external source with html?

Tags: html, button

I'm trying to add a button to my site that initiates a visitor to opt into push web notifications, using push crew.

When you create the button with the service they give you the following code

```
<button onclick="_pcq.push(['triggerOptIn']);">
GET NOTIFICATIONS
</button>
```

Inside there are no options to alter the size, font or colors. I contact their support -> useless.

So the button created is dark grey which turns to light grey when you hover over and white text on both sides.

I have very limited web knowledge, but with googling i found a few codes `<center>` to center the button and a few other codes that work when you place it between `<button` and `onclick` such as `width:150px; height:40px;` to change the size of the button. But i'm still working out how to change the color. If i add `color:red;` it changes the text color which is OK. But if i add the code `background-color: #FFFFC0;` for example it blows out the button. It changes the color of the button but the button no longer works or changes color when hovering over.

The page builder i'm using has html but I don't have access to the CSS, so need a html workaround

Comment: Presumably you can enter CSS inline using a `style="..."` attribute on the button?

Comment: Will the html editor you're using allow `<style>...css...</style>`? Many do, if so it should be pretty easy to add a class or hit it with a selector etc.

Comment: I can add style=" but when i add background-color:... it breaks the button, is there another code to change the button color?

Comment: It breaks it? If you add `type="button"` to it does it still?

Comment: Where would i put that? the code already has <button